# can't set an identifier of type struct to nullptr;

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

I have a struct that looks like this:

```
struct Wolf {
    Wolf *dog;
    Wolf *puppy;
};
```

I have written:

```
Wolf *alphawolf = new Wolf;
```

when I try to set the members dog and puppy to nullptr, it doesn't compile in C++

UPDATE:

I tried:

```
alphawolf.dog = nullptr;
alphawolf.puppy = nullptr;
```

alphawolf and the . is underlined red:
The error is:

this declaration has no storage class or type specifier

Now I used:

```
alphawolf->dog = nullptr;
alphawolf->puppy = nullptr;
```

But I am trying to do this before the main method, "outside main()"
I still get: this declaration has no storage class or type specifier

Comment: Can you show the code that does not compile along with the exact error message copy/pasted from your compiler?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem, on gcc 5.3.1 and -std=c++11 it compiles cleanly the code `Wolf *alpha  = new Wolf; alpha->dog   = nullptr; alpha->puppy = nullptr;`.

Comment: alphawolf is a pointer, you need `->`, not `.` to access its members.

Comment: Yes, Thank you. Now I understand that I should use the -> instead of . But I get the same error message of

this declaration has no storage class or type specifier

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to put executable statements outside of `main()` (or any other function).

If you want to declare a global variable `alphawolf`, with initial values of `nullptr`, the syntax is (outside of `main()`):

```
Wolf alphawolf {nullptr, nullptr};
```

It is also possible to allocate a global `Wolf*` with `new`.  To initialize it, the syntax is:

```
Wolf *alphawolf = new Wolf {nullptr, nullptr};
```

To assign `nullptr` to `alphawolf`'s members, the statements need to be inside `main()`, or some other function.

```
Wolf *alphawolf = new Wolf;
int main() {
    alphawolf->dog = nullptr;
    alphawolf->puppy = nullptr;

    /* Do other stuff with alphawolf */

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for your help. I also created another void function to do it, and it works too.

Comment: It make me sad there's no mention of using a constructor which is the best way to make sure ALL objects are initialized to sane default values.